# Text sticking out in Bootstrap 3 input-goup textarea

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 input-groups, I'm trying to have a textarea with multiple lines. The problem is, in IE 9 (haven't checked other IE versions), the text sticks out of the textarea when there is an input-group-addon to the left of the textarea.

[image: a jsfiddle recreation of the problem]

Check the jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle's recreation](http://jsfiddle.net/dZ5yD/4/)

Horizontal scrollbars appear - though the text box 'ends', the text overflows as you can see in the photo attached.
Another side to the problem is when using a single-line text box, the horizontal scrollbar appears again - though no text is overflowing in this case.

Any ideas on this? These problems don't appear in other browsers  - it's just IE (9).

The HTML:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Text</span>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" id="RandomBox" />
</div>

<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Message</span>
    <textarea class="form-control" cols="5" rows="10" placeholder="Message" style="height: auto;" id="MessageBox">123456789   12345678912 35 6123</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, and found that following the advice in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471406/select-arrow-hidden-in-bootstrap-3-input-group-in-ie9) helped. Basically, add class "pull-left" to your textarea, changing your `class="form-control"` to `class="form-control pull-left"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Eric-king. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine as I've upgraded to IE 11 now and it doesn't have the problem. I'll try to check this on other machines later.

Comment: I was able to use float:left

Comment: @sidesinger That's what the bootstrap `pull-left` class does behind the scenes, but the advantage is that you don't have to use in-line styling and bootstrap may make a few other small adjustments based off of `pull-left` that you won't get with a straight up `float:left` style.

Comment: Well yes, I was't advoacting for inline styles.  I was confirming the solution to the problem.  I did `float:left` inside an existing css class for the matching elements. I think that's a little better semantically.  

Bootstrap defines `pull-left` as: `float:left !important`

Comment: @sidesinger Got it. I think we're in agreement. :-)

Comment: Interesting that pull-left has the effect of making a textarea input group responsive, where it is not out-of-the-box. +1, thanks, fixed my problem.